# Почему вызов функции срабатывает без клика?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
// filter

var withDepositDaily = document.getElementById('with_deposit_daily');
var withDeposit = document.getElementById('with_deposit');
var withDaily = document.getElementById('with_daily');

withDeposit.addEventListener('click', filterWrite("deposit"));
function filterWrite(filterSetting) {
 filterBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_blocks');
 for (var i = 0; i < filterBlocks.length; i++) {
  filterBlocks[i].style.display = 'none';
 };
 for (var i = 0; i < filterBlocks.length; i++) {
  filterAttribute = filterBlocks[i].getAttribute('data-filter');
  console.log(filterAttribute);
  if (filterAttribute == filterSetting) {
   filterBlocks[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
  };
 };
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}.container{max-width:1600px;min-height:800px;border:4px solid green;margin:40px auto}.work_title{display:block;width:100%;height:60px;background-color:#1aff1a}.work_title h1{font-size:32px;color:#006700;text-align:center;padding-top:10px}.filter .filter_category ul{margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px}.filter .filter_category ul li{display:inline-block;font-size:20px;margin-right:16px;font-weight:700;cursor:pointer}.filter .filter_all_blocks{margin-top:20px}.filter .filter_all_blocks .filter_blocks{width:300px;height:200px;background-color:green;border-radius:5px;display:inline-block;margin:20px}.filter .filter_all_blocks .filter_blocks p{font-size:18px;color:#fff}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="work_title">
   <h1>Переключение категорий</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
   <div class="filter_category">
    <ul>
     <li id='with_deposit_daily'>C депозитом и ежедневным бонусом</li>
     <li id='with_deposit'>С депозитом</li>
     <li id='with_daily'>С ежедневным бонусом</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="filter_all_blocks">
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='deposit'>
     <p>С депозитом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='daily'>
     <p>С ежедневным бонусом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='deposit daily'>
     <p>С Депозитоп и Ежедневным бонусом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='deposit'>
     <p>С депозитом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='daily'>
     <p>С ежедневным бонусом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='deposit daily'>
     <p>С Депозитоп и Ежедневным бонусом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='daily'>
     <p>С ежедневным бонусом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_blocks" data-filter='daily'>
     <p>С ежедневным бонусом</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Данный код выводит карточки в зависимости от категорий. Повесил EventListener на элемент, в функции filterWrite указал аргумент, из-за этого функция вызывается сразу же. Как сделать что функция вызывалась все же по клику.

И еще вопрос, код сверяет есть ли у атрибута элемента определенное значение, если таковое имеется, то он выводит на страничку. Но допустим у одного элемента два значения в атрибуте, одно из которых совпадает с  критерием поиска, но почему то такие элементы не выводятся, как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как сделать чтобы функция вызывалась все же по клику.

Вы пишите `filterWrite("deposit")`, что собственно является вызовом функции, чтобы она отрабатывала по клику, нужно передать в обработчик функцию, например так :

```
withDeposit.addEventListener('click', ()=>( filterWrite("deposit") ));
```

или так :

```
withDeposit.addEventListener('click', function(){
  filterWrite("deposit");
});
```

> Но допустим у одного элемента два значения в атрибуте, одно из которых совпадает с критерием поиска, но почему то такие элементы не выводятся, как исправить?

Вы пишете `if (filterAttribute == filterSetting)`, то-есть достаете атрибут с элемента и в данном случае сравниваете его со строкой `'deposit'`, но когда в атрибуте "два значения", то строка получается такой :`'deposit daily'`, и она не равна `'deposit'`, поэтому думаю вам подойдет метод [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), использовать так :

```
if (filterAttribute.indexOf(filterSetting) > -1)
```